# How to call a Symfony controller with post data in a jQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery, symfony, post, jquery-dialog

I'm trying to load a controller with some post value ( because they are datas so not that good to put it in GET ;) ) I tried this :

`$("#dialog").load('http://127.0.0.1:8000/XXX/YYY', {"start" : start} ).dialog('open');`

and in the controller called :

`$start= $request->get("start");`

but I get this : "Notice: Undefined variable: request" Can someone explain me?

EDIT : this is my controller :

```
namespace OurBundle\BuildingBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use OurBundle\BuildingBundle\Entity\Availability;
use OurBundle\BuildingBundle\Form\AvailabilityType;

class AvailabilityController extends Controller
{ 
 public function formAction(Response $request = null ) {
    $iduser = '59';
    $start= $request->get("start");

    $form = $this->createForm(new AvailabilityType( $iduser, $start ), new Availability());

    return $this->render('OurBundleBuildingBundle:Availability:create.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));

}
...
```

I was stupid and forgot the Response, but still doesn't work ( in fact the dialog is empty ( it doesnt display any error ) but it should display a form ( when i put $start == null it does.. )

When I show $request in the view, it always display nothing ( saying it's null )

Comment: Start at the error message `$request->get("start")` so uhm, *why* is that? Seems like an error in PHP not related to jQuery or dialogs. It is *expected* that the `$request` variable to always be defined even for GET or dialog-initiated requests; not being defined is a coding error somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i don't know why but i had to do :

`$start= $this->getRequest()->get('start');`

Answer (score 0):

In your **controller** make sure that you have the **request** as a **parameter**:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DemoController extends Controller
{

    /**
    * @param Request $request
    */
    public function myDemoAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** Get value from request */
        $start = $request->get('start');
   
        // ...
    }

}
```

---

## Quick Tip

If you need a default value for start:

```
    $start = $request->get('start', 'your_default_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this can help you, and also it's not so clear how are you getting `$request` variable (would be better if you include your action to the question), but I think you doing something wrong here: [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) - loads data by POST if you provide object as data, so you're passing object, and POST request is being sent, but why are getting values as `$request->get('start')`?

I think you should follow Patt's answer, but instead of getting values by `$request->get()` you should use '$request->request->get('SOME_DATA')' (by POST), or `$request->query->get('SOME_DATA')` (by GET).